# mysql - how to zero out the access log file?

Tags: mysql, redhat

I have a MySQL 5.5 service (RHEL 5.x) with a ~350Gb access log file. I'd like to zero this file out. Do I need to do anything special before-hand? Stop the server?

Comment: rename the file, use touch to create an empty file with the same name, permissions.  Restart the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you rename the log file, then you issue the command `FLUSH LOGS` which causes MySQL to close and reopen the file.  Since that file doesn't exist, it'll create a new one.

Then do whatever you want with the original file.

No restart necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
shell> cd mysql-data-directory
shell> mv mysql.log mysql.old
shell> mv mysql-slow.log mysql-slow.old
shell> mysqladmin flush-logs
```

refer to : [MySQL :: MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 5.2.5 Server Log Maintenance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/log-file-maintenance.html)

Answer (score 1):

What is access log in MySQL? You mean general_log?
Anyway, rotate any MySQL log with logrotate. Here's sample config. Change log file names.

/root/.my.cnf must store user and password to connect to MySQL

```
# cat /etc/logrotate.d/mysql
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log /var/lib/mysql/general.log {
    compress
    rotate 7
    size 1G
    missingok
    create 640 mysql mysql
    notifempty
    dateext
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
            test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin || exit 0
            MYADMIN="/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/root/.my.cnf"
            if [ -z "`$MYADMIN ping 2>/dev/null`" ]; then
              if ps cax | grep -q mysqld; then
                exit 1
              fi 
            else
              $MYADMIN flush-logs
            fi
    endscript
```

}